# add-DHCPServer4Filter how to use parameter as input

Tags: powershell, dhcp

I am getting error as stated below :

```
Cannot validate argument on parameter 'MacAddress'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty,and then try the command again. + category info : invalidData: (:) [add-dhcpserverv4filter], parameterbidingvalidationexception + fullyqualifiederrorID : parameterargumentvalidationerror, add-dhcpserverv4filter
```

I am getting a mac address and description parameter from other script, so i have the script as below:

```
$mac= "00-01-02-03-04-05"
$desc= "PC-alibaba" 
add-dhcpserverv4Filter -computername pc-alibaba -list allow -macaddress $mac -description $desc
```

So i believe is the parameter causing this error, 
if i use the code below it run without error.

```
add-dhcpserverv4Filter -computername pc-alibaba -list allow -macaddress "00-01-02-03-04-05" -description "PC-alibaba"
```

So what can i do with to make it allow parameters as macadress and description?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what error message do you get?

Comment: @jisaak it show cannot validate argument on parameter 'MacAddress'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty,and then try the command again. 
+ category info : invalidData: (:) [add-dhcpserverv4filter], parameterbidingvalidationexception 
+ fullyqualifiederrorID : parameterargumentvalidationerror, add-dhcpserverv4filter

Comment: hmm, you could try to write `$($mac)` but first check that `$mac` contains something

Comment: @jisaak i am sure it contain something, i tried as below, it still showing the same error
-Macaddress $($FinalMac) -description $($Desc)

Comment: hm okay. Sorry - don't know how to fix that...

Answer (score 0):

The standard debugging way is to use `write-host` to write the parsed command on the console. After that, copy-paste the command back on the command line to see if it runs. Do not type the command you got from `write-host`, use copy-paste in order to use *exactly* the same command you are trying to run. Like so,

```
write-host "add-dhcpserverv4Filter -computername pc-alibaba -list allow -macaddress $mac -description $desc"
```

Comment: Thank for the sharing, appreciate. 
The command i got from the write-host is exactly as what i wrote without using parameter.

Comment: i think i have found the error, becoz i am using invoke session, so i guess the variable did not pass into the session, thank for the help ^^

Comment: @StephenieTan The lesson here is to *include* such a critical piece of information like being on another session on your next question.